# Python GMAIL API Read Full Email Body

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I need to decode email body so it is in human readable text. I have written a function decode_data() that is supposed to ideally decode the message in the email body. However, this doesn't seem to work as I would want it to.
Here's my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
import re
import base64
import email
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = get_credentials()

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        messages_list = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=None, q=None,
                                                        pageToken=None, maxResults=None, includeSpamTrash=None).execute().get('messages')
        for msg in messages_list:
            txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id'],
                                                 format=None, metadataHeaders=None).execute()
            payload = txt['payload']
            headers = payload['headers']
            sender = extract_sender(headers)
            if re.search("^Domo", sender):
                parts = payload.get('parts')
                if parts is not None:
                    parts = parts[0]
                    data = parts['body']['data']
                    decoded_data = decode_base64_data(data)
                    print(decoded_data)

    except HttpError as error:
        handle_api_error(error)


def get_credentials():
    creds = None
    token_file = 'token.json'

    if os.path.exists(token_file):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file, SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        creds = refresh_credentials(creds, token_file)

    save_credentials(creds, token_file)
    return creds


def refresh_credentials(creds, token_file):
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    return creds


def save_credentials(creds, token_file):
    with open(token_file, 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())


def extract_sender(headers):
    for header in headers:
        if header['name'] == 'From':
            return header['value']
    return ''


def decode_base64_data(data):
    data = data.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/")
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    return decoded_data


def handle_api_error(error):
    # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from Gmail API.
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I need help with decoding the body so that instead of getting a result similar to this
[image: log of decoded message]

the code returns just the text needed in a human readable form

Answer (score 1):

I tested your script and I made it work with this slight change in this part of the code:

```
if parts is not None:
                    parts = parts[0]
                    data = parts['body']['data']
                    decoded_data = decode_base64_data(data)
                    print(decoded_data)
```

I changed it to:

```
if parts is not None:
                    parts = parts[0]
                    data = parts['body']['data']
                    #decoded_data = decode_base64_data(data)
                    decoded_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data).decode('UTF8')
                    print(decoded_data)
```

Comment: Hi @Milagro this works for my use case thnaks

Comment: @TitoLulu if this answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.